# Calculate the difference between two dates: not working as expected

Tags: java, android, date

This is my code:

```
public enum MILLI_CONVERSIONS {
//values in milliseconds
SECOND(1000),
MINUTE(1000*60),
HOUR(1000*60*60),
DAY(1000*60*60*24),
WEEK(1000*60*60*24*7),
MONTH(1000*60*60*24*30),
YEAR(1000*60*60*24*31*12);

private final long millis;

private MILLI_CONVERSIONS(final long millis) {
    this.millis = millis;
}

public long getMillis() { 
    return millis; 
}
}

public static String getDateDifferenceFromToday(Date startDate){
Date today = new Date();
long delta = today.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

Integer diff;
String diffText = "";
//seconds
if (delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.MINUTE.getMillis()){ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.SECOND.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " seconds ago";
}
//minutes
else if (delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.HOUR.getMillis()){ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.MINUTE.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " minutes ago";
}
//hours
else if (delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.DAY.getMillis()){ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.HOUR.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " hours ago";
}
//days
else if (delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.WEEK.getMillis()){
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.DAY.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " days ago";
}
// weeks
else if(delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.MONTH.getMillis()){ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.WEEK.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " weeks ago";
}
// months
else if(delta < MILLI_CONVERSIONS.YEAR.getMillis()){ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.MONTH.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " months ago";
}
// years
else{ 
    diff = Integer.valueOf((int) (delta/MILLI_CONVERSIONS.YEAR.getMillis()));
    diffText = diff.toString() + " years ago";
}

return diffText;
}
```

It seems to work fine untill I hit weeks. When it is even a week away, it shows 0 months. And then when it is month, it seemingly gets the right amount of months but it shows "years ago" (ex. if it was two months ago, instead of "2 months ago", it says "2 years ago". And it never hits years, it just keeps going with months (ex. if it was 16 months ago, it should say "1 years ago", but it says "16 years ago").

I am using this with my Android app, so if there are any libraries that do this, or I am missing some built in way to calculate this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Joda Time is by far the best way to do this. Note that not all months are 30 days long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working *way* too hard. Leverage either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package in Java 8.

In general, you should forget about milliseconds. Work with date-time and time zone values so as to let Joda-Time help you with Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies. But if you really are starting from milliseconds, you can use a `long` with Joda-Time.

```
Period period = new Period( myMillis );
```

When you care about a span of time in terms of a number of months, days, hours, and such, use the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class. The [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) class will help you generate a representation as descriptive words such as "15 years and 8 months".

```java
PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
 .printZeroAlways()
 .appendYears()
 .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
 .appendSeparator(" and ")
 .printZeroRarelyLast()
 .appendMonths()
 .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
 .toFormatter();
```

When you have points on the timeline of the Universe (date-time values), use the [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class.

```
Interval interval = new Interval( startDateTime, stopDateTime );
```

You can capture the span of time inside that interval as a Period.

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
```

You might find handy the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard’s definition of a compact and standard way to represent a number of months, days, etc. as a string. The standard calls this a ["duration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (not the same term in Joda-Time). The format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` (for Period) marks the beginning, each `n` is a number, and `T` separates date portion from time portion. Example: `P3Y6M`is three and a half years. In Joda-Time, the Period class knows how to parse and generate such strings.

Search StackOverflow to find many more examples. You are not the first to ask.

Answer (score 2):

When you define your enum constants, you need to do the calculations with long integers since you overflow the integer range. So for example use

```
YEAR(1000L*60*60*24*31*12)
```

instead of

```
YEAR(1000*60*60*24*31*12)
```

Specifying the first number as a long is enough that the calculations are carried out with data type long.

Comment: just a tip.. use L instead of l, because l could be read as 1 (one).